# Extjs grid date column wont display value

Tags: date, extjs, grid

I have a simple grid and below is the basic config.
The grid wont show the date, its empty.
Have any idea y?
This is the json value returning fro, the server:
`"StartAt":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"`
Thanks

```
 {
       model: Ext.define(Ext.id(), {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        fields: [ {
           name: "StartAt",
           type: "date",
           dateFormat: "d-m-Y"
         }]
     }
```

.....

```
columns: {
      items: [{
        id: "StartAt",
        xtype: "datecolumn",
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: "StartAt",
        text: "Offer Start At"
      }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dateFormat` you specified in the model doesn't match what is coming back from the server. The point of specifying it on the model is so it knows how to parse the string that comes from the server. You want: `dateFormat: 'MS'`. On the column, you want to configure: `format: 'd-m-Y'`.

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 5, `dateFormat: 'time'` worked for me. `dateFormat: 'ms'` did not.